# How to get image as a resource instead of string in php using Storage::get()

Tags: php, image, laravel-5

I am trying to give user the photo with desired background that are stored in my server with the text they want on it. But to edit the image on the fly using php , i need to retrieve my background image file as resource but i am getting the image as string instead.

I tried using Storage::get() function. Then I tried to get the url of the file and get_file_contents($url) instead, but no luck.

```
$bg_image = Storage::disk('public')->get('background.png');
imagettftext($bg_image, 64, 10, 20, 20, $color, $font, $user_name);
```

but it threw me an error

> imagettftext() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the php documentation, the function you want is `imagecreatefrompng()` which creates an image resource, which you can pass to your `imagettftext()` function.

```
imagettftext ( resource $image , float $size , float $angle ,
int $x , int $y , int $color , string $fontfile , string $text ) : array

// $image: An image resource, returned by one of the image creation
//    functions, such as imagecreatetruecolor()
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

```
imagecreatefrompng ( string $filename ) : resource

// imagecreatefrompng() returns an image identifier
//    representing the image obtained from the given filename.

// $filename: Path to the PNG image.
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php

There are also other functions for different image filetypes

https://www.php.net/manual/en/resource.php (Ctrl+F 'imagecreate')

Answer (score 0):

The PHP manual for [imagettftext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) says of the `image` parameter that it must be:

> An image resource, returned by one of the image creation functions,
>   such as imagecreatetruecolor().

This means you must first execute a suitable image creation function to read the data from your file and return a resource object. Since you're dealing with a PNG in this case, the [imagecreatefrompng()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) function is likely to be what you need.

Something like this:

```
$resource = imagecreatefrompng("/path/to/background.png")
imagettftext($resource, 64, 10, 20, 20, $color, $font, $user_name);
```